# How to use Facebook Graph search to find pages by amount of likes?

Tags: search, facebook, search-engine

How to use Facebook Graph search to find pages by amount of likes?

I use for example:

```
Shopping & Retail places in United Kingdom
```

And It return all Shopping & Retail places from United Kingdom.

I need to add filter that seek only for pages which have more than 1000 likes how to do that? Is It possible?

Something like that:

`Shopping & Retail places in United Kingdom where likes more 1000`

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Short easy answer: It's not possible right now.

Harder answer (which may or may not break some rules of usage of FB, need to read through actual platform policy, I don't plan to do it so I didn't read): You possibly could load all or as many as you can in browser window, use jQuery inject plugin for Chrome or Firefox to inject jQuery into FB page (or could go without it but it's a bit harder), use developers console and jQuery selectors to check what is the selector for titles link, write JS script that will iterate through them and put into a CSV-like string, write code that will alert that string or inject into page (for example in a comment that can be taken from developers console in HTML/Elements), run that from developers console, copy and paste effect of it into XLS or CSV, write a JS FB app or automation script that will go through list of urls and check how many likes each of them have saving it into xls or csv, put it all together, filter it in any tool like open office / ms excel.